# Parsing a number from a file with using AWK

Tags: string, parsing, awk, scripting

I have a file that contains windows "systeminfo" info. The file looks like this:

```
Virtual Memory: Available: 13,160 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    3,143 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 13,161 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    3,142 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 13,162 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    3,141 MB
```

I want to parse only the number and store in a csv file. 
so one csv file will be named as "available.csv" and contains

```
13,160;13,161;13,162.
```

The other csv file named as "in_use.csv"will contain `3,143;3,142,3,141`.

I know I can use:
`grep -r "Available" > available.csv` and then only extract the number.

How do I accomplish this with using awk ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk '/Available/{ printf "%s%s",(!a)?"":";",$4 > "available.csv"; a++ }
     /In Use/{ printf "%s%s",(!b)?"":";",$5 > "in_use.csv"; b++ }' input
```

Answer (score 0):

**GNU awk** solution. More general approach as far as filenames are concerned:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{FS=": +"}
{ split($3,a," ")                              # remove the MB from number
  gsub(/ /,"_",$2)                             # replace space by "_"
  f=tolower($2) ".csv"                         # construct filename
  printf "%s%s", (file[f]++?";":""), a[1] > f  # output number to file
}
END { for (f in file) close(f) }               # close all opened files
```

for copy-and-paste:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=": +"} \
       { split($3,a," ");gsub(/ /,"_",$2);f=tolower($2) ".csv"; \
         printf "%s%s", (file[f]++?";":""), a[1] > f} \
       END { for (f in file) close(f) }' input.txt
```